# How to prevent player object from clipping through walls in a 2d environment

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

The player box is continuing through walls in an undesired fashion, I have tried making it so that the player moves in 0.1f(u) increments at a time, but this severely drops the performance of the game. Is there any way I can detect if the player is hitting a wall, what side they hit it on and how can I prevent them from clipping into the wall?

Here is the code that I am running (this is minimalistic of course)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Platformer
{

    public class Player
    {
        double terminalVelocity;
        //AnimatedTexture texture;
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Vector2 Position, Velocity;
        public Rectangle boundingBox;
        public Player(Texture2D tex, Vector2 pos, Vector2 vel, Rectangle bb)
        {
            texture = tex;
            Position = pos;
            Velocity = vel;
            boundingBox = bb;
            terminalVelocity = Math.Sqrt((2*bb.Width*bb.Height*Game1.gravity)/-9.8*2);
        }

        public void updateBoundingBoxes()
        {
            boundingBox.X = (int)Position.X;
            boundingBox.Y = (int)Position.Y;
        }

        public void onUpdate()  
        {
            updateBoundingBoxes();
            Position.X += Velocity.X;
            Position.Y += Velocity.Y;
            //Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
            Velocity.Y += Game1.gravity / 60;
            Velocity.X /= 1.2f;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            updateBoundingBoxes();
            sb.Begin();
                sb.Draw(texture,boundingBox,GameLighting.currentColour());
            sb.End();
        }

    }

    public enum GameLightingState
    {
        Red, Dark, Orange, Blue, White
    }

    public class Platform : Object
    {

        Texture2D text;
        public Rectangle rect;
        public Platform(Texture2D t, Vector2 p, int sizeX, int sizeY)
        {

            text = t;
            rect = new Rectangle((int)p.X, (int)p.Y, sizeX, sizeY);


        }

        public void onPlayerCollision(Player p)
        {
            p.Velocity.X = -p.Velocity.X / 2;
            p.Velocity.Y = -p.Velocity.Y / 2;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            sb.Begin();
               sb.Draw(text, rect, GameLighting.currentColour());
            sb.End();
        }

        public void onUpdate()
        {

        }

    }

    public class GameLighting
    {
        public static Color currentColour()
        {
            return eToColour(Game1.currentLightingState);
        }

        public static Color eToColour(GameLightingState gls)
        {
            switch (gls)
            {
                case(GameLightingState.Red):
                    return Color.Red;
                case (GameLightingState.Blue):
                    return Color.Blue;
                case (GameLightingState.Orange):
                    return Color.Orange;
                case (GameLightingState.Dark):
                    return Color.DarkGray;
                case (GameLightingState.White):
                    return Color.White;
            }
            return Color.White;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        public static float gravity = 9.80665f;
        public static GameLightingState currentLightingState;
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        List<Platform> platforms;
        List<Player> players;
        int controlledPlayerIndex = 0;
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            currentLightingState = GameLightingState.White;
            platforms = new List<Platform>();
            players = new List<Player>();
            players.Add(new Player(this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/dirt"), new Vector2(300,0), new Vector2(0,0), new Rectangle(300,0,20,20)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/dirt"),new Vector2(300,450),200,20));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/dirt"), new Vector2(20,20), 20, 200));
            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
            foreach (Player p in players)
            {
                Boolean intersects = false;
                Rectangle tempRectangle = new Rectangle((int)(p.Position.X + p.Velocity.X),(int) (p.Position.Y + p.Velocity.Y), p.boundingBox.Width, p.boundingBox.Height);
                foreach (Platform pl in platforms)
                {
                    intersects = intersects || tempRectangle.Intersects(pl.rect);
                }
                if (!intersects)
                {
                    p.onUpdate();


                }
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                players[controlledPlayerIndex].Velocity.Y -= 0.75f;
            }
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) 
            {
                players[controlledPlayerIndex].Velocity.X -= 0.75f;
            }
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                players[controlledPlayerIndex].Velocity.X += 0.75f;
            }

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            foreach (Platform p in platforms)
            {
                p.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            foreach (Player p in players)
            {
               p.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

*Updated Source Code based on first comments

One note about this code, you need to run it in XNA and use an icon called dirt.png in a folder called Images, it doesn't matter what the picture looks like, you just need it to fully understand what is happening

Comment: Don't update a player before you check for collisions. You're essentially moving them into the wall before you check if they're in there. Instead, do a "hit-test". Simulate the move and then check for collisions.. if it is.. don't update their position. If it isn't colliding.. continue with your normal update of their position.

Comment: onPlayerCollision, don't just set the velocity to 0 - also move the player back outside of the wall.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead but what if I am still 15 u up from the floor, that would just leave the character object floating

Comment: @mbeckish I have no way of knowing which way they came from though, so even if i could predict a side, it would be inaccurate towards the position

Comment: @blazingkin - p.Velocity is a vector.  Move the player back out in the opposite direction of p.Velocity before setting p.Velocity to 0.

Comment: @mbeckish so that kindof worked, but my plan is to include wall jumping so I need players to stick to the wall briefly before making the second jump, not sure how this would quite work either, but i suppose one step at at time I updated the code as well to include some changes, not making the player clip, but still freezing above the platform

Comment: @blazingkin The simluation doesn't have to be a single step. Besides, there's an `Intersects` overload that returns the `Rectangle` representing the intersection. You can use that to update the correct distance (so if you're moving by 20u but the player is 15u from the floor.. the `Rectangle` returned will be 5u in height.. although I like @mbeckish's solution too).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem recently myself. Here is what I did.

```
//variables needed
public bool follow = true;
public Vector2D startpoint;

//puts the startpoint value equal
//to the inital location of the player
public Player()
{
    startpoint.X = rectangle.X;
    startpoint.Y = rectangle.Y;
}

//if any of the collision tests fail
if(collision occurs)
{
    collision();
}
//else update startpoint to new valid location
else 
{
    startpoint.X = rectangle.X;
    startpoint.Y = rectangle.Y;
    follow = true;
}
if(follow == true)
{
    //movement commands occur
}
else
{
    follow = true;
}

//if a condition fails set player
//too last valid location
public void collision()
{
    rectangle.X = startpoint.X;
    rectangle.Y = startpoint.Y;
    follow = false;
}
```

This worked well enough for me hope it helps.